# Javascript mutator issue in pseudo class

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mutators

Here is the code:

```
var Circle = function( radius )
{
    var _radius = radius,
    _area = function()
    {
        return Math.PI * _radius * _radius;
    },
    _perimeter = function()
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * _radius;
    };

    this.radius = _radius;
    this.area = "Area" + _area();
    this.perimeter = "Perimeter" + _perimeter();
    this.setRadius = function( radius ) {
        _radius = radius;
    };
};
```

However I cannot get the this.setRadius() function to successfully mutate the private properties. For instance, I run this:

```
var circle = new Circle(5);
alert(circle.area);
circle.setRadius(10);
alert(circle.radius);
```

And it outputs 78.blah which is correct, then it outputs a radius of 5.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! I thought that since the _area property is a function, it would recalculate each time, but I guess it's not? but why is this.radius not returning the new radius when it is obviously being reset?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Alright, thanks for why the radius isn't working correctly. That is a little obvious. As pointed out, I do not ever update this.radius. However, the point remains that the _area and _perimeter values are not updated either.

I run:

```
var circle = new Circle(5);
alert(circle.area);
circle.setRadius(10);
alert(circle.area);
```

And I still get the old area even after updating the radius. Note that the _area function is dependent on _radius and not this.radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I decided to do it the following way:

```
var Circle = function( radius )
{
    var _radius = radius;

    this.radius = function()
    {
        return _radius;
    };
    this.area = function()
    {
        return Math.PI * _radius * _radius;
    }
    this.perimeter = function()
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * _radius;
    }
    this.setRadius = function( radius ) {
        _radius = radius;
    };
};
```

It works now. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is because you're not setting the radius property in the setRadius function.

You set the private property _radius but there is nothing in your function that updates the this.radius.

EDIT:  I updated my answer to how i would have solved this problem.  Could be better I guess but just a simple way of doing it.

```
var Circle = function( radius )
{
    var radius, area, perimeter;

    this.setRadius = function( radius ) {
         var _radius = radius,
        _area = function()
        {
            return Math.PI * _radius * _radius;
        },
        _perimeter = function()
        {
            return 2 * Math.PI * _radius;
        };

        this.radius = _radius;
        this.area = "Area" + _area();
        this.perimeter = "Perimeter" + _perimeter();
    };

    this.setRadius(radius);
};
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense for why it is not setting this.radius. But it will also not update the area when I run circle.area after setting the radius differently. Why is this?

Comment: _radius is being reset, and _area is dependent on _radius not on this.radius

Comment: you have your function modeled in a procedural fashion.  Which means items get executed in a certain order.  By redefining the radius, you will need to recalculate the rest of the math to make everything correct.  The code you placed doesnt do this automatically.